# Building central installer that can install software on several servers

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to create an MSI installer with Wix that can be run on one server and install different window services on several other servers that are on the same network.

The installer should be able to prompt the user for which servers they want to install on and for each server the user will then choose which window services they want installed. One of the reasons for creating a central installer instead of requiring the user to run it on each machine is because there are some steps that only need to be setup once for the entire suite of services (like the database) and we don't want to require the user who's setting up our product to have to remote into every server and run an installer.

From what I've seen about Msi's though is that they are meant for a single box install and I haven't found much info online on multiple server installations from a single installer. Any suggestions on how to implement such an installer or different tools to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed this as an answer even it is not really an answer - simple reason: the comment field is too limited for this response.

MSI does not support (and should not support) this feature out of the box. A MSI package is build to install a single application on a single machine. There are concepts like chaining (which is not recommended, anyhow) which might help you on a local machine.

You need to create your own bootstraper which includes the logic to deploy s/w on other machines (you might start with burn, but I have my doubts that this can be managed easily there). Microsoft is doing this a lot (have you ever seen how many MSI packages are installed if you install a Lync Server farm?).

A suggestion might be to create a central operations tool that installs a database which is accessible trough the network. As a next step you start installers on the target machines that request the tools/operations to be performed from the central database. I think there're already tools in the market (think about SCCM from Microsoft).

My personal point: My admins would kill me if I spread software through the network without their knowledge :)